# Sweetalert2 problem with bootstrap modal and jquery 3.6

Tags: html, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, sweetalert2

sweetalert2 confirm button not clickable (missing focus) when bootstrap modal is open. Please help. I found no solution to this problem on the Internet. Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `code`<button type="button" value="<?php echo $kod; ?>" class="btn btn-outline-info ukaz_obj_dod" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#ModalObjednavky">
                                                                                            Objednávky u dodavatelů
                                                                                        </button>`code`

Comment: `code`<div class="modal fade" id="ModalObjednavky" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">.........
                </div>`code`

Comment: `code`Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Upozornění',
                    text: "Opravdu chcete provést výmaz této objednávky?",
                    icon: 'warning',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#28c76f',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#ea5455',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Ano',
                    cancelButtonText: 'NE, zrušit'
                }).then((result) => {
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        ........
                    }
                });`code`

Comment: The above is the part of the code. Unfortunately, I cannot insert large texts.

I open Modal "ModalObjednavky" and click on the Delete button. Opens swal.fire (Modal "ModalObjednavky" is still open). I need my Focus on the Confirmbuttontext button in the swal.fire window.

Nowhere did I find how to do it. Thank you very much for your help.